# change visibility of a div based on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I already checked

- [CSS and hiding/showing divs when radio button checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035092/css-and-hiding-showing-divs-when-radio-button-checked)
- and
  [If Radio button checked show div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730218/if-radio-button-checked-show-div)

My problem is a little bit different I use WordPress and in the input generated by WordPress there is no `id` and in fact, the front generated is like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabiei/eL41p83v/), I can not change the HTML code.

Is there any solution to only show `id="DateDD"` if users clicked on `Choose delivery date`

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabiei/eL41p83v/)**

**Update:**

Code added.

```html
<h5 class="text-brown pt-4">Please select delivery date:</h5>
<div class="form-check">
  <div data-priority="" class="form-row my-field-class form-row-wide pl-3" id="send_date_field">
    <fieldset>
      <legend></legend><label><input type="radio" name="send_date" value="Send as soon as possible"> Send as soon as possible</label><label><input type="radio" name="send_date" value="Choose delivery date"> Choose delivery date</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="pl-1-3 pr-4 pt-2 mb-n2" id="DateDD">
    <div id="orddd_dynamic_hidden_vars"><input id="orddd_recurring_days" name="orddd_recurring_days" type="hidden" value="on"><input id="orddd_weekday_0" name="orddd_weekday_0" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_1" name="orddd_weekday_1" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_2" name="orddd_weekday_2" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_3" name="orddd_weekday_3" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_4" name="orddd_weekday_4" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_5" name="orddd_weekday_5" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_weekday_6" name="orddd_weekday_6" type="hidden" value="checked"><input id="orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled" name="orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled" type="hidden" value="no"><input id="orddd_delivery_dates" name="orddd_delivery_dates" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_specific_delivery_dates" name="orddd_specific_delivery_dates" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_delivery_date_holidays" name="orddd_delivery_date_holidays" type="hidden" value="&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021&quot;"><input id="orddd_lockout_days" name="orddd_lockout_days" type="hidden" value="false"><input id="orddd_enable_time_slider" name="orddd_enable_time_slider" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_show_datepicker" name="orddd_show_datepicker" type="hidden" value="datepicker"><input id="orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery" name="orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery" name="orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery" type="hidden" value="on"><input id="orddd_disabled_days_str" name="orddd_disabled_days_str" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_disabled_weekdays_str" name="orddd_disabled_weekdays_str" type="hidden" value="&quot;8-26-2021&quot;,"><input id="orddd_next_day" name="orddd_next_day" type="hidden" value="27-8-2021"><input id="orddd_current_day" name="orddd_current_day" type="hidden" value="26-8-2021"><input id="orddd_minimumOrderDays" name="orddd_minimumOrderDays" type="hidden" value="27-8-2021"><input id="orddd_current_date_to_check" name="orddd_current_date_to_check" type="hidden" value="26-8-2021"><input id="orddd_number_of_dates" name="orddd_number_of_dates" type="hidden" value="30"><input id="orddd_partially_booked_dates" name="orddd_partially_booked_dates" type="hidden" value=""><input id="orddd_available_deliveries" name="orddd_available_deliveries" type="hidden" value="'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',"><input id="orddd_minimum_delivery_time" name="orddd_minimum_delivery_time" type="hidden" value="24"><input id="orddd_enable_shipping_delivery_date" name="orddd_enable_shipping_delivery_date" type="hidden" value="on"><input id="date_mandatory_for_shipping_method" name="date_mandatory_for_shipping_method" type="hidden" value=""><input id="time_setting_enable_for_shipping_method" name="time_setting_enable_for_shipping_method" type="hidden" value="off"><input id="time_slot_enable_for_shipping_method" name="time_slot_enable_for_shipping_method" type="hidden" value="off"></div><input type="hidden" name="h_deliverydate" id="h_deliverydate" value="27-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_unique_custom_settings" id="orddd_unique_custom_settings" value="custom_settings_2"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_date_holidays" id="orddd_delivery_date_holidays" value="&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021&quot;"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_lockout_days" id="orddd_lockout_days" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_min_hour" id="orddd_min_hour" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_min_minute" id="orddd_min_minute" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_min_hour_set" id="orddd_min_hour_set" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_min_mins_set" id="orddd_min_mins_set" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_max_hour_set" id="orddd_max_hour_set" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_max_mins_set" id="orddd_max_mins_set" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_from_hours" id="orddd_delivery_from_hours" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_from_mins" id="orddd_delivery_from_mins" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_current_day" id="orddd_current_day" value="26-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_current_hour" id="orddd_current_hour" value="02"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_current_minute" id="orddd_current_minute" value="00"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_next_day" id="orddd_next_day" value="27-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_minimumOrderDays" id="orddd_minimumOrderDays" value="26-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_min_date_set" id="orddd_min_date_set" value="27-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_current_date_set" id="orddd_current_date_set" value="26-8-2021"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_number_of_dates" id="orddd_number_of_dates" value="60"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_number_of_months" id="orddd_number_of_months" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_timeslot_field_mandatory" id="orddd_timeslot_field_mandatory" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_shipping_method_hidden_vars_arr" id="orddd_shipping_method_hidden_vars_arr" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_current_time" value="1629943222"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_same_day_delivery" name="orddd_same_day_delivery" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_next_day_delivery" name="orddd_next_day_delivery" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_time_settings_selected" id="orddd_time_settings_selected"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_admin_url" id="orddd_admin_url" value="https://spanishclub.ie/wp-admin/"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_is_admin" id="orddd_is_admin" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_is_cart" id="orddd_is_cart" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_is_account_page" id="orddd_is_account_page" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_date_on_cart_page" id="orddd_delivery_date_on_cart_page" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_field_label" id="orddd_field_label" value="Delivery Date"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_timeslot_field_label" id="orddd_timeslot_field_label" value="Time Slot"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_field_name" id="orddd_field_name" value="e_deliverydate"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_auto_populate_first_available_time_slot" id="orddd_auto_populate_first_available_time_slot" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_time_format" id="orddd_delivery_time_format" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_autofill_of_delivery_date" id="orddd_enable_autofill_of_delivery_date" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_shipping_based_delivery" id="orddd_enable_shipping_based_delivery" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_shipping_days" id="orddd_enable_shipping_days" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_date_field_mandatory" id="orddd_date_field_mandatory" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_availability_display" id="orddd_enable_availability_display" value="on"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_show_partially_booked_dates" id="orddd_show_partially_booked_dates" value="on"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_0" name="orddd_shipping_day_0" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_1" name="orddd_shipping_day_1" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_2" name="orddd_shipping_day_2" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_3" name="orddd_shipping_day_3" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_4" name="orddd_shipping_day_4" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_5" name="orddd_shipping_day_5" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_shipping_day_6" name="orddd_shipping_day_6" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_zone_id" id="orddd_zone_id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_shipping_id" id="orddd_shipping_id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_category_settings_to_load" id="orddd_category_settings_to_load" value="shipping-method,24-hours,shop-by-region,castile-and-leon,salamanca,ham"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_shipping_class_settings_to_load" id="orddd_shipping_class_settings_to_load" value="truck-and-airplane,plane"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_common_delivery_days_for_product_category" id="orddd_common_delivery_days_for_product_category" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_common_delivery_dates_for_product_category" id="orddd_common_delivery_dates_for_product_category" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_common_holidays_for_product_category" id="orddd_common_holidays_for_product_category" value="&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021&quot;,&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021&quot;"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_common_locked_days" id="orddd_common_locked_days" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_is_days_common" id="orddd_is_days_common" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_categories_settings_common" id="orddd_categories_settings_common" value="no"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_0" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_1" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_2" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_3" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_4" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_5" value="checked"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_weekday_6" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled" name="orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_load_delivery_date_var" id="orddd_load_delivery_date_var" value="{&quot;orddd_weekday_0&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_1&quot;:&quot;checked&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_2&quot;:&quot;checked&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_3&quot;:&quot;checked&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_4&quot;:&quot;checked&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_5&quot;:&quot;checked&quot;,&quot;orddd_weekday_6&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_specific_delivery_dates" id="orddd_specific_delivery_dates" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_recurring_days" id="orddd_recurring_days" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disable_for_delivery_days" id="orddd_disable_for_delivery_days" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disable_for_holidays" id="orddd_disable_for_holidays" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_dates" id="orddd_delivery_dates" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_time_slot" id="orddd_enable_time_slot" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_enable_time_slider" id="orddd_enable_time_slider" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_time_slider_min_time" id="orddd_time_slider_min_time"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disable_minimum_delivery_time_slider" id="orddd_disable_minimum_delivery_time_slider" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_shipping_method_based_settings" id="orddd_shipping_method_based_settings" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disabled_days_str" id="orddd_disabled_days_str" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disabled_weekdays_str" id="orddd_disabled_weekdays_str" value="'8-26-2021'"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_option_str" id="orddd_option_str" value="beforeShow:maxdt&amp;dateFormat:'DD, M d, yy'"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_date_format" id="orddd_delivery_date_format" value="DD, M d, yy"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_show_datepicker" id="orddd_show_datepicker" value="datepicker"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_start_of_week" id="orddd_start_of_week" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_field_note_text" id="orddd_field_note_text" value="We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date."><input type="hidden" name="orddd_hidden_vars_str" id="orddd_hidden_vars_str" value="[{&quot;unique_settings_key&quot;:&quot;custom_settings_1&quot;,&quot;product_categories&quot;:&quot;4-working-days&quot;,&quot;shipping_methods_for_categories&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enable_delivery_date&quot;:&quot;on&quot;,&quot;date_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;time_slots&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timeslot_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;hidden_vars&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;orddd_recurring_days\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_0\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_1\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_2\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_3\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_4\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_5\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_6\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled\&quot;:\&quot;no\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_specific_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_date_holidays\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021\\\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_lockout_days\&quot;:false,\&quot;orddd_enable_time_slider\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_show_datepicker\&quot;:\&quot;datepicker\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_days_str\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_weekdays_str\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;8-26-2021\\\&quot;,\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_next_day\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_day\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimumOrderDays\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_date_to_check\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_number_of_dates\&quot;:\&quot;30\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_partially_booked_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_available_deliveries\&quot;:\&quot;'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time\&quot;:\&quot;100\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;time_settings&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orddd_delivery_checkout_options&quot;:&quot;delivery_calendar&quot;,&quot;orddd_min_between_days&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;orddd_max_between_days&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time&quot;:&quot;100&quot;,&quot;orddd_date_field_label&quot;:&quot;Delivery Date&quot;,&quot;orddd_time_field_label&quot;:&quot;Time Slot&quot;},{&quot;unique_settings_key&quot;:&quot;custom_settings_2&quot;,&quot;product_categories&quot;:&quot;24-hours&quot;,&quot;shipping_methods_for_categories&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enable_delivery_date&quot;:&quot;on&quot;,&quot;date_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;time_slots&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timeslot_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;hidden_vars&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;orddd_recurring_days\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_0\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_1\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_2\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_3\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_4\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_5\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_6\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled\&quot;:\&quot;no\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_specific_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_date_holidays\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021\\\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_lockout_days\&quot;:false,\&quot;orddd_enable_time_slider\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_show_datepicker\&quot;:\&quot;datepicker\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_days_str\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_weekdays_str\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;8-26-2021\\\&quot;,\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_next_day\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_day\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimumOrderDays\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_date_to_check\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_number_of_dates\&quot;:\&quot;30\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_partially_booked_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_available_deliveries\&quot;:\&quot;'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time\&quot;:\&quot;24\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;time_settings&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orddd_delivery_checkout_options&quot;:&quot;delivery_calendar&quot;,&quot;orddd_min_between_days&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;orddd_max_between_days&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time&quot;:&quot;24&quot;,&quot;orddd_date_field_label&quot;:&quot;Delivery Date&quot;,&quot;orddd_time_field_label&quot;:&quot;Time Slot&quot;},{&quot;unique_settings_key&quot;:&quot;custom_settings_3&quot;,&quot;product_categories&quot;:&quot;48-hours&quot;,&quot;shipping_methods_for_categories&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enable_delivery_date&quot;:&quot;on&quot;,&quot;date_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;time_slots&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timeslot_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;hidden_vars&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;orddd_recurring_days\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_0\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_1\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_2\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_3\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_4\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_5\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_6\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled\&quot;:\&quot;no\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_specific_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_date_holidays\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021\\\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_lockout_days\&quot;:false,\&quot;orddd_enable_time_slider\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_show_datepicker\&quot;:\&quot;datepicker\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_days_str\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_weekdays_str\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;8-26-2021\\\&quot;,\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_next_day\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_day\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimumOrderDays\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_date_to_check\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_number_of_dates\&quot;:\&quot;30\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_partially_booked_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_available_deliveries\&quot;:\&quot;'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time\&quot;:\&quot;60\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;time_settings&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orddd_delivery_checkout_options&quot;:&quot;delivery_calendar&quot;,&quot;orddd_min_between_days&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;orddd_max_between_days&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time&quot;:&quot;60&quot;,&quot;orddd_date_field_label&quot;:&quot;Delivery Date&quot;,&quot;orddd_time_field_label&quot;:&quot;Time Slot&quot;},{&quot;unique_settings_key&quot;:&quot;custom_settings_4&quot;,&quot;product_categories&quot;:&quot;cheese&quot;,&quot;shipping_methods_for_categories&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;enable_delivery_date&quot;:&quot;on&quot;,&quot;date_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;time_slots&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;timeslot_field_mandatory&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;hidden_vars&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;orddd_recurring_days\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_0\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_1\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_2\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_3\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_4\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_5\&quot;:\&quot;checked\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_weekday_6\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_is_all_weekdays_disabled\&quot;:\&quot;no\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_specific_delivery_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_delivery_date_holidays\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;2021 January 1   Spain:1-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 January 6   Spain:1-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 June 24   Spain:6-24-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 12   Spain:10-12-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 November 1   Spain:11-1-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 6   Spain:12-6-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 8   Spain:12-8-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 August 2   Ireland:8-2-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 October 25   Ireland:10-25-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 27   Ireland:12-27-2021\\\&quot;,\\\&quot;2021 December 28   Ireland:12-28-2021\\\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_lockout_days\&quot;:false,\&quot;orddd_enable_time_slider\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_show_datepicker\&quot;:\&quot;datepicker\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_same_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_custom_based_next_day_delivery\&quot;:\&quot;on\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_days_str\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_disabled_weekdays_str\&quot;:\&quot;\\\&quot;8-26-2021\\\&quot;,\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_next_day\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_day\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimumOrderDays\&quot;:\&quot;27-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_current_date_to_check\&quot;:\&quot;26-8-2021\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_number_of_dates\&quot;:\&quot;30\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_partially_booked_dates\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_available_deliveries\&quot;:\&quot;'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',\&quot;,\&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time\&quot;:\&quot;24\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;time_settings&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orddd_delivery_checkout_options&quot;:&quot;delivery_calendar&quot;,&quot;orddd_min_between_days&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;orddd_max_between_days&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;orddd_minimum_delivery_time&quot;:&quot;24&quot;,&quot;orddd_date_field_label&quot;:&quot;Delivery Date&quot;,&quot;orddd_time_field_label&quot;:&quot;Time Slot&quot;}]"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_delivery_checkout_options" id="orddd_delivery_checkout_options" value="delivery_calendar"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_minimum_delivery_time" id="orddd_minimum_delivery_time" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="orddd_disable_delivery_fields" id="orddd_disable_delivery_fields" value="no"><input type="hidden" id="orddd_partially_booked_dates" class="orddd_partially_booked_dates" value=""><input type="hidden" id="orddd_available_deliveries" name="orddd_available_deliveries" value="'>Available Deliveries: Unlimited',"><input type="hidden" name="add_tooltip_for_weekday" id="add_tooltip_for_weekday" value=""><input type="hidden" name="orddd_first_autofil_delivery_date" id="orddd_first_autofil_delivery_date" value="">
    <style type="text/css">
      .holidays {
        background-color: #ff0000 !important;
      }

      .booked_dates {
        background-color: #ff0000 !important;
      }

      .cut_off_time_over {
        background-color: #ff0000 !important;
      }

      .available-deliveries,
      .available-deliveries a {
        background: #90EE90 !important;
      }

      .partially-booked,
      .partially-booked a {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff000059 0%, #ff000059 50%, #90EE90 50%, #90EE90 100%) !important;
      }

    </style>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="e_deliverydate_field" data-priority="" style=""><label for="e_deliverydate" class="">Delivery Date</label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text hasDatepicker" name="e_deliverydate" id="e_deliverydate" placeholder="Choose a Date" value="" style="cursor:text !important;"></span><br><small class="orddd_field_note">We will try our best to deliver your order on the specified date.</small></p>
    <div class="orddd_text_block" style="display:none">
      <h3>Delivery Information</h3>

      <p>Your Estimated shipping date for the order is <b><span id="shipping_date">Thursday, Aug 26, 2021</span></b></p>
      <p>The delivery will take approximately <b><span id="orddd_between_range">1-3</span></b> working days from the shipping days.</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="orddd_estimated_shipping_date" id="orddd_estimated_shipping_date" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is generally advised to include the code/snippet in the body of the question; off-site resources may be subject to change, which would render the post useless to subsequent visitors if the original conditions were no longer available for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your JSFiddle, you would need to target the `name` attribute on those radio selects. If the value equals "Choose delivery date" show the delivery date div.

```
const deliveryDate = document.getElementById('DateDD');
const sendOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="send_date"]');

// Hide initially
deliveryDate.style.display = 'none';

// Add event listeners to both radios,
// Show deliveryDate based on value of selected radio
sendOptions.forEach((send) => {
  send.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === 'Choose delivery date') {
      deliveryDate.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      deliveryDate.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```